The request queue limit of the session is exceeded (no cookies/loadtest)
I'm working on a CMS System (Sitecore) built using ASP.NET.
When performing a load test we are getting high error rates linked to the following error:
"The request queue limit of the session is exceeded".
I've read a number of articles related to this (including the two below) but am struggling to see how they apply to us:
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/34439/the-request-queue-limit-of-the-session-is-exceeded
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0858026
The reason I'm struggling to see the link is that when performing our load tests it appears that no cookie/session data is provided in the request. Additionally, my understanding is that each thread in our load test should run sequentially, so I find it strange that a queue would build up.
Is anyone able to suggest/explain why these errors could be happening and what the behavior is behind the scenes when requests start coming in with no session data?
My assumption was that a new and unique session ID would be created for the each request and this might be added to the queue but given we are not resubmitting the cookie on subsequent requests this queue should never grow.
The test plan we are running was created with JMeter and is executed on BlazeMeter. We have "Clear cookies on each iteration" enabled and I believe that each iteration results in a single request being made (the requests trickle down via Throughput Controllers to HTTP Requests).
Thanks in advance for any support or suggestions,
Daniel
